# Remove Characters After Number

Tags: python

I have a string from a file which I need to remove all the characters after the substring "c1525". Can regex be used for this? The pattern I am seeing is that all my strings have a "c" then 4 digits (although I have seen more than 4 digits, so need to take that into consideration).

```
d098746532d1234567c1525qFPXplFSm-FS8575664637338586224hKwHFmFSRRnm0Uc006566
```

expected:

```
d098746532d1234567c1525
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to remove everything after a string using Python re.sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54037046/how-to-remove-everything-after-a-string-using-python-re-sub)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex with a capturing group and `re.sub`:

```
import re

s = 'd098746532d1234567c1525qFPXplFSm-FS8575664637338586224hKwHFmFSRRnm0Uc006566'

s2 = re.sub(r'(c\d{4,}).*', r'\1', s)
```

output: `'d098746532d1234567c1525'`

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'd098746532d1234567c1525qFPXplFSm-FS8575664637338586224hKwHFmFSRRnm0Uc006566'
s[:s.find('c1525')+len('c1525')]
```

Output:
`d098746532d1234567c1525`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> txt = "d098746532d1234567c1525qFPXplFSm-FS8575664637338586224hKwHFmFSRRnm0Uc006566"
>>> import re
>>> re.match("[^c]*(c\d+)", txt).group()
'd098746532d1234567c1525'
```